# Active Record Relations Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Let's say I have Profile Model, Test Model and TestItem model.
Profile has many test_items, and Test has one test_item.

TestItem just represents, that test was added to profile (the way it is usually done with Cart-Product-LineItem) (So when we add TestItem to Profile it is not new Test, as when we add LineItem to Cart it is not new Product).

I want Profile to have many TestItems, but I need to specify, that this TestItems should belong to different Tests. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

```
class Profile
  has_many :test_items
end

class TestItems
  belongs_to :profile
  belongs_to :test
end

class Test
  attr_accessible :test_item 
end
```

Comment: you mean I need to remove has_one? Can you please explain what will it achieve?

Comment: you can have has_one instead of attr_accessible. in fact it may be better. but this relationship overall should achieve what you're looking for.